# How to print cookie matching a name from a cookiejar

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies

Assuming I have a CookieJar populated with cookies, what is the best way to print the cookie value that matches a given cookie name?

```
for cookie in cj:
   print(cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.domain)
```

Gives:

```
JSESSIONID AB782061C5F81345CC5743978F08734E www.test.com
PHPSESSID 5dc439530b5d8a3df50392a193c58832 test.tv
csrftoken Md6KVSRl8sg9BNIUAKIq4Jk9F4iHYLK3tPZJL7HfLbwmfwVrzknnf5eLhGybUQOQ test.com
...
```

How can I print all cookie value for `csrftoken` as an example?

Comment: `if cookie in cj: print(cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.domain) else: print('cookie not found')`

Answer (score 1):

My one liner solution:

```
cookie=[c.value for c in cj if c.name == 'csrftoken']; print(cookie)
```